# Try Catch Doesn't Work

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm getting this stack trace in the output window of XCode 4:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Page bottom]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfbdb1f0'
```

However, the calling code has a try catch

```
@try {
    [self restoreStateWithControlSurfaces:result];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Failed at restoreStateWithControlSurfaces %@", exception);
    retVal = NO;
}
```

It might have something to do with `NSHangOnOtherExceptionMask` but I'm not sure how this fits together. How can I get my catch block to work? This is in the simulator for iPad 4.2.

Comment: Is it possible that `[self restoreStateWithControlSurfaces:result];` isn't the cause of the exception?  Or even that the exception is occurring on another thread?

Comment: @Alex Nichol, no, thanks to XCode letting me click through the stack trace... see accepted answer (below).

Comment: it was noted at WWDC 2011 that **none** of the engineers at Apple use the simulator, they all have a device tethered to their development machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A bug has been reported](http://openradar.appspot.com/8081169) that prevents `NSInvalidArgumentException` from being caught.  This bug appears to affect the simulator only.

Comment: that is hilarious (because it's not mission critical today for me). Thanks!